# Right and left gaps issue on mobile site

Tags: blogger

There is a problem with my blog, there are no gaps on the main page. Gaps appear when I view the subject. How do I fix the page?

Home page: https://ibb.co/Mh0Ft0b
Looking into the subject: https://ibb.co/vh6g1dB

Comment: Show the site code or URL?

Comment: https://bilgialfa.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gaps are not an issue, they are padding of the element `#main-wrapper`. In order to reduce the padding on mobile devices, use the following CSS rule to override the existing one

```
@media (max-width: 900px) {
    .item #main-wrapper { padding: 10px; }
}
```

If you want to reduce the padding on all devices, just use

```
.item #main-wrapper { padding: 10px; }
```

Note: you can set the value `10px` as you like.

Comment: Which number should be written?

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
#main-wrapper{float:none;overflow:hidden;width:100%}
#sidebar-wrapper{width:100%;margin:10px auto;float:none;padding-left:0 }
#footer{padding:20px 0}
.sect-left{width:100%;margin-right:0}
.sect-left .widget{padding:20px}

Comment: Ok, you have to target item pages not homepage so you need to search this css rule `.item #main-wrapper` and change `padding: 25px`

Comment: Working.Thanks, God bless you!